# How should I integrate video.js in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, video.js

I am looking for a reference or an example of how to integrate video.js in a meteor application. I don't want to use a package since I plan to add plugins to video.js.

Here are the elements I understood (correct me if I'm wrong):

- video.js should be loaded in client/compatibility folder in order to be loaded first
- It seems a script and style elements must be created. See [here](https://github.com/GitYong/meteor-videojs/blob/master/yong:meteor-videojs.js)
- On the page where the video.js player is, it is necessary to load it from js since we are in a dynamic HTML context.

A couple of questions:

- Is there an easy way to change the lang and font path?
- Are all the files in the video.js download mandatory for using it
  (except the demo files I guess)?

All feedbacks on a video.js integration in meteor are welcome.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package:

```
> https://atmospherejs.com/yong/meteor-videojs
> https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/videojs
```

Github Link

```
https://github.com/Slava/talk-player/blob/master/client/player.js
```